# How to organize so that decimals are in order?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am uploading a contract to Sharepoint so the the first column, which will decide the order is listed by number (1.1,1.2,1.3 and forward). However, Sharepoint sees values like 1.1 = 1.10 when those are in different sections of the contract and 1.10 actually comes after 1.9. Is there a way to make sure the column ascends with this in mind? Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of your column? Maybe you should change the type of it to "Text"

Comment: How do you achieve the order number listed? Using Power Automate flow, calculated column or anyway else?